# Simplest way of forwarding all mail from server?

Tags: debian, software-rec, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lightweight outgoing SMTP server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server)

I am looking for a minimal mail solution (MTA) for a headless server which generate e-mails for local users and and fully qualified addresses from cron-jobs, etc.
Ideally all mails to local user `foo` should be mapped to `foo@mydomain`, with possible modifications for `uid`<1024, and sent off to an external smtp server without involving `/var/mail`.

Some years ago, I used [sSMTP](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp) for a similar task, and I was wondering if this is still the way ahead? Also, how much of the default debian mail system should/could I remove?

---

**Update** Ended up Googling a bit, and the obvious candidates seem to be

- [sSMTP](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp): Not actively developed
- [eSMTP](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/): Not actively developed according to home page
- [mSMTP](http://linux.die.net/man/1/msmtp): Recommended in front of sSMTP at http://www.scottro.net/qnd/qnd-ssmtp.html
- [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/): Suggested by Gilles

Even though [eSMTP](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/) is not developed anymore, it seems to have the nicest documentation. It doesn't quite fit my needs though, at it seems to insist on delivering mail to local user `foo` via a Mail Delivery Agent (MDA) instead of pushing it out over smtp to `foo@some.domain`. Or maybe it does do the mapping if I add `qualify_domain` to the config. Might have to try it out...
[nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) appears to be running a queue in `/var`, which is not something I want.

Does anybody have experience with any of these?

Comment: Oops -- possible dupe of this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server

Comment: I closed as a duplicate, but I don't think it can be cleanly merged; most of these answers reference the question in ways that won't make sense on the other post

Comment: this post shows how to quickly setup postfix with gmail smtp port 587 and test it, and how to set your own email to receive all mail to root:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731560/346155

Answer (score 7):

[Nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) might fit the bill:

> Nullmailer is a mail transport agent designed to only relay all its
>   messages through a fixed set of "upstream" hosts.

If you just install the Debian package, it will replace whatever MTA was there before.

Comment: Thanks. Seems `nullmailer` does queuing in `/var` which is something I want to avoid. http://www.l3jane.net/cgi-bin/man/man2html?8+nullmailer-send . Now I got googling, so I'll expand the question with a few alternatives :)

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be nullmailer too. We were in a similar situation before (need to use a second MTA in Zimbra boxes for system-generated mail) and it fits the bill nicely.

However, your requisite of not using /var is a hurdle. Could you elaborate on the reasons why? If the problem is using the disk at all, you could mount nullmailer's queue on tmpfs. It wouldn't be quite safe, but at least it wouldn't touch the disk at all.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want to avoid `var` to keep the disk idle. You are right about `tmpfs` of course, but I'd like to keep it as simple as possible...

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the easiest way to do this is to install postfix (if debconf asks you questions, pick "internet site"), then run these commands:

```
postconf -e relayhost=other.mailserver.com
postconf -e mailname=my.domainname.com
```

As long as the SMTP server specified in `relayhost` doesn't require authentication, allows you to relay or is a valid destination for the recipient address this will work.

The `mailname` parameter will be the default domain name. So if you send mail to foo it will go to foo@my.domainname.com. Mail sent by user bar will be from bar@my.domainname.com.

If you do need to authenticate and want to support TLS, also run the following commands:

```
postconf -e smtp_tls_security_level=may
postconf -e smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
postconf -e smtp_sasl_password_maps=pcre:/etc/postfix/sasl_password_maps
```

Then in `/etc/postfix/sasl_password_maps` have this content:

```
/./ username:password
```

All mail will be sent to your relayhost with the specified username and password.

Comment: I'll need the authentication. Plain could work, but StartTLS would probably be nice. But installing postfix seems like it would be massive overkill?!

Comment: I updated my answer to include client auth and TLS support.