# How to setup a simple email daemon with autorespond and mail forwarding?

Tags: email, daemon

Since my mail provider unfortunately offers neither an autoresponder nor forwarding mail to others during vacancy, I'd like to setup e.g. a RaspberryPi to regularly check my mail account (via POP3 or IMAP), and react on new email by sending an autoreply à la "I'm currently on vactation" to the sender (maybe with some smart only-once-per-week-and-recepient mechanism) and redirecting (not forwarding; i.e. resending the original mail) the mail to someone else (without deleting it of course). What's the simplest way to achieve this? Solutions that do not require me to set up my own mailserver would be appreciated...

**edit** Sending should simply use SMTP on the same account the mail is retrieved from, i.e. basically the solution should simply automate what I can locally already do using Thunderbird, without requiring any mailserver setup
**edit2** Could a simple cronjob involving `mutt` suffice for this?

Comment: You could use e.g. `getmail` to fetch the mails, `procmail` to process them (forwarding / auto-responding) and `nullmailer` for sending mails. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/simplest-way-of-forwarding-all-mail-from-server or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server for related threads.

Comment: @jofel Thanks for the hint and the links, I'll check if they already answer my question

Comment: Instead of `procmail` you can also use `maildrop` which could be easier. The [getmail FAQ](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/faq.html) contains the information how you can link these programs.