# how to redirect all email to a single external address?

Tags: email, mail-transport-agent

I have a headless server (`rpi1.example.com`) with two active accounts: `pi` and `root`. I would like all the emails sent to these accounts to be redirected to an external address: `real@somewhere.net`.

Right now I use `nullmailer` with the following setup:

```
# /etc/nullmailer/adminaddr
real@somewhere.net

# /etc/nullmailer/defaultdomain
example.com

# /etc/nullmailer/defaulthost
rpi1

# /etc/nullmailer/remotes
smtp.somewhere.net smtp
```

This setup works, except for addresses like `pi@rpi1.example.com`:

- an email to that address is generated on `rpi1.example.com`
- ... which sends it out via `smtp.somewhere.net`
- ... which then tries to resend it to the `MX` of `rpi1.example.com`
- ... which does not exist as no email is expected to arrive there

How to setup this "outbound-only" MTA which would redirect/forward all internal emails to a single address?

Comment: fwiw you can usually use `/etc/aliases` to specify a full email address for destination but only using the local username for the source. If you use `postfix` you would then set `relayhost` and `myorigin` as appropriate to send the emails to the upstream SMTP server.

Comment: see my answer on this question that is not frozen, for using postfix and smtp port 587 and /etc/aliases: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731561/346155