# How to rewrite an outgoing email address on the fly?

Tags: email, mail-transport-agent

Follwing up on [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195029/how-to-redirect-all-email-to-a-single-external-address) about headless and real-user-less setups, I am trying to find an alternate way of handling outgoing emails directed to local users (email outgoing from my machine `rpi1.example.com` is directed to `pi@rpi1.example.com`) which should actually be sent to a single external address.

Is there maybe a way to **rewrite** on the fly (as it is being processed for sending) the address of the intended recipient of an email, so the  so that it actually reads `real@somewhere.net` ?

- I would like to avoid using an MTA for inbound email (in other words,
  accepting incoming emails).
- I do not have concerns about privacy (all the accounts on the box are
  mine and are technical accounts)

Comment: see the answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65013/understanding-etc-aliases-and-what-it-does), which explains how to use /etc/aliases to accomplish this.

Comment: @gogoud that suggestion doesn't perform a rewrite of the header, which is what I think WoJ also wants.

Comment: @roaima, it must rewrite the header because the 'To:' address becomes the address specified in /etc/aliases (I use it all the time).