# Suggestions for IRC Server

Tags: linux, irc

I am planning to setup an IRC server for our internal communication needs. Which of the IRC servers do you guys suggest? Things I am looking for:

- Should not be very complex to setup
- Should allow running of bots written in ruby.
- Integration with [Hubot](https://github.com/github/hubot) would be good.
- Should allow reserving nicks based on password

Comment: Although I appreciate the question, how exactly does this related to Unix/Linux?

Comment: @MaxMackie I want this to be deployed on my linux server, use it from ubuntu clients. I've seen some pretty good suggestions on other similar stuff. Checkout this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server or any of the questions in the related questions on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've moved through a few ircd's and settled on [NgIRCd](http://ngircd.barton.de/) - a free open source server for Internet Relay Chat (IRC), which is being developed under the GNU General Public License (GPL). It has been written from scratch and is consequently, unlike most other IRC daemons, not based on the originator, the daemon of the IRCNet

- well arranged (lean) configuration file
- simple to build/install, configure and maintain
- supports IPv6 and SSL
- no problems with servers that have dynamic IP addresses
- freely available, modern, portable and tidy C-source

IRC bots / Hubot will connect to the IRCd as clients - they shouldn't be dependent on a particular IRCd

You can use [anope](http://www.anope.org/about.php) to add a nickserv service through [ngircd services](http://ngircd.barton.de/doc/Services.txt) - this is what you'll need to reserve nicknames.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have already installed Unrealircd, will check this out.

Comment: Could you perhaps also recommend a client which is web-based (no software to install) e.g. in JavaScript? Or would you recommend a non-IRC chat instead if all clients are web browsers?