# Problem mounting disk raid0

Tags: mount, fdisk, rescue

I did a rescue reboot for my server OVH and I connected to my server by ssh. Then I tried to mount my disk as I normally do but I can't get it.

This is the result of the command tried:

```
root@rescue:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 593223E8-887A-4821-B0C6-1649D623D455

Device           Start         End     Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1           40        2048        2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sda2         4096    80873471    80869376   38.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sda3     80873472 11719991295 11639117824    5.4T Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  11719991296 11721037823     1046528    511M Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdc: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D19C5407-BC61-4727-B881-1A232260832E

Device           Start         End     Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sdc1           40        2048        2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdc2         4096    80873471    80869376   38.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc3     80873472 11719991295 11639117824    5.4T Linux RAID
/dev/sdc4  11719991296 11721037823     1046528    511M Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdd: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F8BC6212-1C93-4565-8945-A1E0F1EB6AF2

Device           Start         End     Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sdd1           40        2048        2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdd2         4096    80873471    80869376   38.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd3     80873472 11719991295 11639117824    5.4T Linux RAID
/dev/sdd4  11719991296 11721037823     1046528    511M Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdb: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A8CCBAD5-CACC-4FE4-A3D7-2FA3C4BB8272

Device           Start         End     Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sdb1           40        2048        2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2         4096    80873471    80869376   38.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3     80873472 11719991295 11639117824    5.4T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  11719991296 11721037823     1046528    511M Linux swap

root@rescue:~# mount -t devtmpfs /dev/sda1 /mnt
root@rescue:~# mount -t devtmpfs /dev/sda2 /mnt/home
mount point /mnt/home does not exist
```

And I created a folder in `/mnt` named `home`, and mounted `sda2` in `/mnt/home`.  The result:

```
root@rescue:~# df -h
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1                             16G  1.5M   16G   1% /
/dev/sda1                            16G     0   16G   0% /mnt
91.121.126.137:/home/pub/rescue.v8  1.8T  292G  1.4T  18% /nfs
tmpfs                                16G  1.5M   16G   1% /rw
91.121.126.137:/home/pub/pro-power  1.8T  292G  1.4T  18% /power
91.121.126.137:/home/pub/commonnfs  1.8T  292G  1.4T  18% /common
tmpfs                                16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                16G   10M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                16G  444K   16G   1% /tmp
root@rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]           [multipath] [faulty]
md2 : inactive sda2[0](S) sdc2[4](S) sdd2[3](S) sdb2[2](S)
161738496 blocks

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: You should run `mdadm`to test/assemble the raid: `mdadm --assemble --scan` or `mdadm -D /dev/md2` (as md2 is marked inactive). See `man mdadm` and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28636/how-to-check-mdadm-raids-while-running

Answer (score 0):

Your `mount` command doesn't make sense. You are mounting a `devtmpfs` RAM-based filesystem on `/mnt` with a name of `/dev/sda1`. This is not referencing the filesystem on `/dev/sda` at all.

Perhaps you mean this:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mkdir -p /mnt/home
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/home
```

But even this doesn't really make any sense given you're talking about RAID filesystems. If the RAID arrays are built from `/dev/sd[abcd]2` or /`dev/sd[abcd]3` then you need to refer to the RAID devices `/dev/md2` and perhaps `/dev/mdY` (for some value of `Y`).

Comment: root@rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]           [multipath] [faulty]
md2 : inactive sda2[0](S) sdc2[4](S) sdd2[3](S) sdb2[2](S)
161738496 blocks