# Understanding /etc/aliases and what it does

Tags: email

This is the contents of the file `/etc/aliases` on my Debian (Wheezy) server, as it is:

```
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: t
```

1. I noticed that, by default, my server sends emails from what looks like `root@hostname.domain.com`. So, which one of the rules above governs this? `postmaster: root`?
2. So, the rules in `/etc/aliases` are used to assign users to specific departments? For example, all emails to be sent/received for `abuse` will be delivered from/to `root@hostname.domain.com` (which would be the default email for root, unless there's an alias). Correct?
3. Can someone please explain what each of these is really meant for? -- `mailer-daemon`, `postmaster`, `nobody`, `hostmaster`, `usenet`, `news`, `webmaster`, `www`, `ftp`, `abuse`, `noc`, `security`, `root`.

   I mean, a description like *"`mailer-daemon` is for sending email delivery errors, but not really meant for receiving emails. `security` for where people should contact you about security issues"*, or something like that.

Comment: I think the easiest way to understand /etc/aliases is to use it to forward all mail to root to your own email: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731560/346155

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `/etc/aliases` file is part of `sendmail`. It specifies which account mail sent to an alias should really be delivered to.  For example, mail to the `ftp` account would be sent to root's mailbox in the configuration you show.

Multiple recipients can be specified as comma-separated lists, too.

Redirecting mail to users isn't all that can be done.  Mail can be piped to programs, too, or simply directed into a file of your choice.  The following would "bit-bucket" all mail for the user `somebody`:

```
somebody: /dev/null
```

Modifications to the `/etc/aliases` file are not complete until the `newaliases` command is run to build `/etc/aliases.db`.  It is in this later form that `sendmail` actually uses.

Comment: So, is there a `security` daemon too? ('security' is listed in /etc/aliases.) When exactly is it triggered?

Comment: More generally it specifies to whom mail should be delivered when addressed to the `alias` on this host.  Mail to `ftp` would be delivered to the `root` mailbox. Although it is often used to redirect locally generated/delivered mail to somewhere useful it works for email from anywhere and from anyone, if accepted by sendmail and the config says to use the alias file.

Comment: You should use ` character instead of ' at the last paragraph.

Comment: Nearly every modern *nix MTA is sendmail compatible. The existence of `/etc/aliases` does not mean it uses sendmail. Postfix and exim4 both use `/etc/aliases` as well.

Comment: @mindthemonkey: (... and JRF) What is the significance of the last line (I guess the OP's username is `t`)? Also, although I have `/etc/aliases`, I don't have `/etc/aliases.db`, and `newaliases` gives me the following (error) message: `p11-kit: duplicate configured module: gnome-keyring-module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so`.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg All you can say from the last line is that all mail for `root` will be delivered to `t`.  Probably ask a separate question for that sendmail issue. It looks like something for secure smtp is messed up. Does your sendmail run at all then?

Comment: @mindthemonkey: Yes, I get the syntax; I only wonder why it is there. I have the same thing last (`root: <user>`), and I'm on Debian as well. I don't know how to check if sendmail is working? Of course I could write a question; just thought you might know once we are at it.

Comment: If you're being a "good sysadmin" you would avoid using the root account where possible, so forwarding mail to a normal user means you need root less. In any case, if I need system mail it gets forwarded out to normal pop/imap accounts that people check.

Answer (score 5):

`mailer-daemon`, `hostmaster` and `postmaster` are special mail addresses required by various RFC's, with the apparent exception of `mailer-daemon` which we can regard as being "entrenched by convention or tradition".

You need `mailer-daemon` in order to handle issues related to mail itself, such as SMTP bounce messages. If your mail server receives an undeliverable message, it generates an SMTP non-delivery notice, whose From: address is `mailer-daemon`. The alias is there in case someone replies to a bounce message; it goes to the `postmaster`, who is a human being, which "mailer daemon" isn't.  I can't find any RFC which describes `mailer-daemon` let alone requires it.  You could probably rename this alias to something else like `mailer-server`, but then you would have to reprogram your mail server to identify itself as `mailer-server` when sending bounces.  I can't think of a reason why bounces couldn't just be from `postmaster`.

[RFC 2142](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142), section 5, gives a summary of some special aliases, and points to other RFC's where they are introduced. Here we learn that  `postmaster` is specified as far back as RFC 822 (it is in its section 6.3).  It is a requirement for mail sites to have this alias. `hostmaster` is mentioned in RFC's 1033, 1034 and 1035. The other aliases you're wondering about are also given in 2142.