# Delivery Status Notification (Delay) emails from my server?

Tags: debian, email, exim

I am using a Debian Jessie server and have [setup](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-exim-to-send-email-using-gmail-in-debian) [exim4](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#Debian_Exim4_User_FAQ) to send me emails instead of postfix or sendmail.

Thats when I started getting loads of emails as follows:

**First:**

> Title: *** SECURITY information for vultr.guest ***
>
> Body: vultr.guest: Dec  7 12:13:29 : root : unable to resolve host vultr.guest

**Second:**

> Title: Cron  test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
>
> Body:
>
> ```
> This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification
>
> THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.
>
> YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.
>
> Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
>
>      root@example.com
>
> Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)
>
> Technical details of temporary failure:
> The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720
> [(10) example.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.90]:25: socket error]
>
> ----- Original message -----
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>         d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
>         h=from:to:subject:mime-version:content-type:content-transfer-encoding
>          :message-id:date;
>         bh=k/8GlT8DBvBIJzBOOfw8qR0kGPzj7m9ZR/aj+JOKBhg=;
>         b=eA6kpVtS0eNBO0CFBfLzlnaYwZ9/GubMaWTGUkG4MaxbNy55YxY2jZAuh3RHI2mo8Q
>          qp5OmKihchYTgCxcAx0xvJaXuuxDhoT9dCJ6YEIzqjmypWjpUEqoXkNu7uKU4Cd1vTfS
>          5/dSvE7zVE6TYe4L18vrOiYBEUNrJQ3lTdv//RrlHZs/f62GorIyMHgVL4XvkVNLWF/K
>          lK9SSybf9ee3KTKUxurBm1Tyah62Gk4/869Hynr1QEAjSAzM8sSKDyKH/KOZ06sDWtPQ
>          jE0Agxffk8RkhsFkEtIbpZBfS/zagGZ8+CXsGqR9541ylMAHGOGeYtRp4oiB8tVP2Sbv
>          h4Rw==
> X-Received: by 10.129.114.10 with SMTP id n10mr3081975ywc.0.1449600002717;
>         Tue, 08 Dec 2015 10:40:02 -0800 (PST)
> Return-Path: <myEmailAddress@gmail.com>
> Received: from vultr.guest ([104.156.246.90])
>         by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id f203sm2998216ywf.45.2015.12.08.10.40.02
>         for <root@example.com>
>         (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
>         Tue, 08 Dec 2015 10:40:02 -0800 (PST)
> From: Cron Daemon <myEmailAddress@gmail.com>
> X-Google-Original-From: root@example.com (Cron Daemon)
> Received: from smmsp by vultr.guest with local (Exim 4.84)
>         (envelope-from <smmsp@example.com>)
>         id 1a6NBB-0007Vu-Os
>         for root@example.com; Tue, 08 Dec 2015 13:40:01 -0500
> To: root@example.com
> Subject: Cron <smmsp@vultr> test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
> X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=root>
> X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
> X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/var/lib/sendmail>
> X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
> X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=smmsp>
> Message-Id: <E1a6NBB-0007Vu-Os@vultr.guest>
> Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2015 13:40:01 -0500
> ```

I edited `/etc/cron.d/sendmail` and first tried to change the `MAILTO=` line from `root` to my gmail address. That did not help. So I commented that line out, and the

```
*/20 *    *    *    *       smmsp   test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
```

That made it stop from sending me emails every 20 minutes with junk. But I still get many and often emails with the

Subject: *** SECURITY information for vultr.guest ***
Body:

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

     root@example.com

Message will be retried for 1 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720
[(10) example.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.90]:25: socket error]
```

I did modify `/etc/hostname` and removed `vultr.guest` and replaced it with `example.com`. And in `/etc/hosts` I only have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   install.install install

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

What did I configure wrong? And how can I fix it?

**UPDATE: The `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` contents are:**

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='satellite'
dc_other_hostnames=''
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='smtp.gmail.com::587'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Comment: I have added it to the end of the question. Thanks

Comment: It's difficult without knowing what `example.com` really refers to. But Google is telling you it doesn't know how to deliver to `root@example.com`. Correct the destination address to something valid.

Comment: example.com is the domain name I have. root@example.com is the root user. What is needed to be done in order to setup a mailbox for root? I thought it goes to `/var/mail/root`

Comment: You need to tell `exim` it is the local machine so it does local delivery! I'll write a proper answer shortly

Comment: Actually, I do not know if it is relevant or not - but three days ago I configured exim4. Until then I had to go and visit `/var/mail/root` to see notifications. Once I changed to exim4, I do not see any changes made to the `/var/mail/root` or `/var/mail/mail` files. Can that be a clue to the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that VULTR's tutorial is not correct. When you configure exim4 by `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`, they tell you to choose `mail sent by smarthost; no local mail`, and configure it as follows:

```
System mail name: YOUR_HOSTNAME
IP-addresses to listen on for incoming SMTP connections: 127.0.0.1 ; ::1
Other destinations for which mail is accepted: <BLANK>
Visible domain name for local users: <BLANK>
IP address or host name of the outgoing smarthost: smtp.gmail.com::587
Keep number of DNS-queries minimal (Dial-on-Demand)? No
Split configuration into small files? No
Root and postmaster mail recipient: <BLANK>
```

But I doubt that the `Other destinations for which mail is accepted:` should be `BLANK`. If you configure it, add your email address, or your `example.com` domain/email.

Otherwise, try to edit the following locations:

[/etc/aliases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65013/understanding-etc-aliases-and-what-it-does):

```
root: address@example.com
mailer-daemon: address@example.com
postmaster: address@example.com
nobody: address@example.com
hostmaster: address@example.com
usenet: address@example.com
news: address@example.com
webmaster: address@example.com
www: address@example.com
www-data: address@example.com
ftp: address@example.com
abuse: address@example.com
noc: address@example.com
security: address@example.com
*: address@example.com
```

and edit `/etc/email-addresses` to include the user:email combo:

```
root: address@example.com
mail: address2@example2.com
*: address@example.com
```

Then restart 
`service sendmail restart` and `service exim4 restart`

Comment: Interesting, `man etc-email-addresses` does not mention that `*` can be used in `email-addresses` in Debian 8 (Jessie). Maybe I should report documentation bug? It's convenient feature to know.