# Lightwight MTA which could listen on localhost port

Tags: port-forwarding, mail-transport-agent

I have multiple Ubuntu servers with Java applications running on it. One of the application's functions is to sent an email. Now we using `exim4` as the MTA.

I would like to replace `exim` with something lighter. My first idea was `msmtp` or `ssmtp`.
Mail from command line gone well, but then I found the problem:

Java application trying to sent an email on `localhost:25` and getting the following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

and it is correct behavior since msmtp/ssmtp does not listen on `localhost:25`.
I am not able to change the Java code, so I need to pick up an email on `localhost:25` on server and then put it to central mailserver through SMTP. Is there any way to run msmtp/ssmtp as a daemon listening on `localhost:25` ? Or maybe forward `localhost:25` to msmtp/ssmtp's `STDIN` somehow?

Comment: I think nullmailer fits the bill.

Comment: @Gilles nullmailer doesn't listen on port 25, it merely provides an implementation of `sendmail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to change Java code from *localhost* to mailserver address

Answer (score 1):

The links below provides all the MTA choices you can choose, according to your Ubuntu version:

[MTA - Ubuntu 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mail-transport-agent)

[MTA - Ubuntu 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mail-transport-agent)

You can also check the Archwiki page on Setting up ssmtp to use port 25.

SSMTP and MSMTP still are not full fledged MTA's. This [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server) provides details for a comprehensive lists of MTA's available and they as well are already packaged for ubuntu.