# how to get the run results of the cron job

Tags: cron

I wrote a simpleWorld Java Program and created a jar file of it.

Now to test the cron job, wrote a crontab.txt file with the line

```
50 12 27 4 1 java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

and saved it.

At the command prompt on unix box, I wrote:

```
crontab crontab.txt
```

I don't see the result of the program on the unix box.
How do I get the SysOut line "Hello World".

In other words, how do I know if it ran successfully or not?

Answer (score 3):

The best ("correct") way to do it is to modify the command in the crontab
so that it redirects its output; e.g.,

```
50 12 27 4 1 java -jar HelloWorld.jar >> HelloWorld.output 2>&1
```

But, normally, when a cron job produces output that is not redirected,
`cron` captures it and mails it to you. 
Try typing `mail` and see what you get. 
(If you have some other mail system on your machine, use that, of course.)

Comment: to run at 1:25pm,25 01 27 4 1 java -jar HelloWorld.jar >> HelloWorld.output 2>&1

Comment: and if i use mail, this is the error message
mail
crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.
crontab: errors detected in input, no crontab file generated.

Answer (score 1):

If a cron job produces any output, cron sends it to you via the local email facility. If a cron job returns a nonzero (i.e. error) status, cron sends you an email about it. There's no robust way to check whether a cron job has finished with no output and a zero (i.e. success) status, or it's still running.

Some distributions don't set up a local email facility in their default installation. It's usually easy to do that: just install one of the [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) packages such as Postfix or Exim; select “local delivery only” or some such when asked how to configure it. If you want the emails to be sent to a remote server over SMTP rather than delivered locally, [there are minimal MTAs just for that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server).

Instead of or in addition to the email, you can arrange for the output of your job to go into a file, by using a redirection on the command line.

```
50 12 27 4 1 java -jar HelloWorld.jar >~/log/HelloWorld-$(date -d \%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M\%S).log 2>&1
```